# set_locale in wordpress - woocommerce - stripe

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, locale

**Hello**

my locale setting work everywhere except in stripe geteway plugin ( have asked stripe and woocommerce support : no solution )

detail of the probleme/bug here
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/issues/701

new info for this
testing this morning with the hook "wc_stripe_localized_messages"

```
add_filter("wc_stripe_localized_messages", function($arr_def){
$lang = WPTBASE::$theme_var["lang"];
WPTBASE::init_lang( $lang ); // this init lang and local
$wp_locale = get_locale(); // wp locale val

print "<pre>"; 
print "theme locale = " . WPTBASE::$theme_var["local"] . "\n";
print "wp locale = " . $wp_locale . "\n";

print $lang . "\n";
print  $arr_def["invalid_number"]; 

print "\n";
print __( 'The card number is not a valid credit card number.', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' );    

print "</pre>";   
return $arr_def;
});
```

this ouput at the top of the checkout page
https://www.support-rack.com/sr_2018/ca/eng/checkout/
this :

> theme locale = en_CA
>
> wp locale = en_CA
>
> eng
>
> Le numéro de la carte de paiement n’est pas un numéro de carte de paiement valide.
>
> Le numéro de la carte de paiement n’est pas un numéro de carte de paiement valide.

the wordpress locale is en_CA
but the __() ouput is french ?

**help !**

Comment: chaged wp general setting language to english, then back to french. Now Stripe label are always in english? This make me belive that this is a reel bug.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve !
Wordpress french locale file is 'fr_CA' / canada
the stripe french locale file is fr_FR / france
I'm using fr_CA .....
details / details / details
this was a friday exercice